# how to return None in dictionary which id is not present in dictionary?

Tags: python

How do I identify the age of the employee with employee id `106` (which is not present in the dictionary)? If the employee isn't present return `NA`.

How do I do this?

```
employee_id = {101: 43, 102: 25, 103: 43}
print(employee_id[106])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
print(employee_id.get(106))
```

instead.

If you want to return some value other than `None`, make it the second argument to `.get()`.